# Format Text under Editing tools is disabled in sharepoint wiki

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have user custom master page in Wiki. When I change to edit mode (site Action\ Edit Page), the Editing Tools came out under Ribbon menu.

However, Clipboard,Font and Paragraph...sections are all disabled.

Do you know how to resolve it?

I even tried to check out, but same thing happened

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue using Google Chrome 15.  For me, it was the "Screen Capture (by Google)" plugin (version 5.0.3) which was causing this error: "Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP."  Disabling the extension fixed the issue, and I'm now able to use Font, Paragraph, Markup sections.

Try disabling some extensions in Firefox/Chrome.  If that doesn't work, try another browser and report back.

Comment: For me, it was the adblock extension. I was able to add an exemption for my sharepoint side ("Don't run for pages in this domain" option), reload, and editing came back up.